# Evaluate the double integral via triangle region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Consider $B$ as the triangular region consisting of vertices $(0, 0)$, $(\pi, 0)$ and $(\pi/2, \pi/2)$ thus evaluate $$\int _{B} \int \sin(y + x) dB$$

We split this into 2 regions $B_1, B_2$ and see the integral is the sum of the double integral over those regions.

I seem to get $1 - 1 = 0$ at the end, which seems fishy.

Comment: inside the triangular region $B$ we have $0\leq y+x\leq \pi $ and therefore $\sin (y+x)\geq 0$ so the definite integral can't be zero

Comment: @Lozenges, can you suggest a hint otherwise?

Comment: Write what you have tried so we can debug your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint...consider a change of variables so that $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$. The Jacobian is $-\frac 12$.

So your integral becomes $$I=-\frac 12\int_{u=0}^{\pi}\int_{v=0}^{-u}\sin u dvdu$$ and the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Alternatively if you want to stick to the same variables, you can split the integral into $$I_1=\int_{x=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{y=0}^{x}\sin(x+y)dydx$$ and $$I_2=\int_{x=\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\int_{y=0}^{\pi-x}\sin(x+y)dydx$$

Adding the results gives the same answer $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

It is:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_y^{\pi-y} \sin{(x+y)} dxdy=\int_0^{\pi/2} -\cos{(x+y)}\bigg|_y^{\pi-y}dy=$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 1+\cos{2y}dy=(y+\frac{1}{2}\sin{2y})\bigg|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$